# Not getting post by title in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have to try belove code to get post by title but I am not able to get a post

```
$data = get_posts( array( 'post_title' => 'Gallery','post_status'=>'inherit') );
```

this gives me a null response and some it gives all post list

Answer (score 3):

Try to retrieve your posts by [wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) class as follows:

```
global $wpdb;
$myposts = $wpdb -> get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title LIKE '%s'", '%'. $wpdb->esc_like($title) .'%'));

foreach ($myposts as $mypost) 
{
    $post = get_post($mypost);

    // add your code here for a post processing

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with following.

```
$args = array('s' => 'Gallery','posts_per_page' => -1);

$your_searchposts = get_posts($args);
```

**OR**

```
$args = array('s' => 'Gallery','posts_per_page' => -1,'post_status'=>'any');

$your_searchposts = get_children($args);
```

Comment: function get_gallery() {
 $args = array('s' => 'Gallery','posts_per_page' => -1,'post_status'=>'inherit');
 $data = get_posts($args);
 print_r($data);
 $response = new WP_REST_Response($data);
 $response->set_status(200);
 return $response;  
}

Comment: Have you checked your database for "gallery" post inherit status in exists or not ? And i also suggest you check with post_status => any

Comment: Is it possible to share screenshot ?

Comment: @blkerai I have tried code with post status inherit or any both working fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195397/discussion-between-dhruv-and-blkerai).

Answer (score 0):

you can get post by bellow code:

```
$args = array("post_type" => "mytype", "s" => $title);
$query = get_posts( $args );
```